# HTML Table Issues - flush to screen edge

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to make a table that's content sits flush with the edge of the screenspace. However no matter what I've tried, it doesn't seem to like it. Its formed a gap roughly ten pixels wide around the table, which I would like gone.
Is it possible to make the contents of the table flush to the edge of the screen?

Here's a screenshot of the gap:

[image]

Here's a snippet for the table:

```html
<body style="background-color:#4d4d4d" >
  <table width="100%" border="0" padding="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th height="504" colspan="2" background="Website Specific Resources/Full Header_White.png" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

http://pastebin.com/fEgLt0fU

Comment: Learn some more tools of the trade. Use a browser side tool to inspect your table (and body). Chrome and IE have inbuilt tools for Firefox there is the Firebug plugin (my client side dev tool of choice). I'd put money on there still being padding on the `body` element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the margin to 0px as well

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this one was inspired straight from Jon,
Adding "leftmargin="0px" and etc. to the body element was the fix.
Thanks all for your help.